# After Win10 2004 update can no longer connect to my samba server

Tags: windows-10, samba, opensuse

I run an openSUSE 15.1 server with samba shares. I've always been able to connect to my shared folders using Windows 10. However, after the Win10 2004 (May 2020) update I now get this:

> Error code: 0x80070043
> The network name cannot be found.

I can ping the server and even connect to it using another PC w/o the update, so it appears something is now broken. Has anyone else experienced this?

**EDIT**: My smb.conf file contains `win protocol = SMB2`. Changing to SMB3 had no effect. Purpose of this post is to see if anyone else who upgraded to 2004 is also running into this problem.

**EDIT #2**: I verified that other Windows 10 computers on my network (same version) can still access the server shares so not sure what's up with this one PC. It's doing some other strange things as well, like not connecting to port 80 on this same server when using its public DNS.

Comment: I was going under the assumption that you had enabled SMBv1 in order to connect to your Samba network share.  Once the feature update was installed, optional Windows Features have a habit of being uninstalled, when a feature update is installed. The age of the possible duplicates does not change the fact, they could have been duplicates, it seems your question is light on the specifics of your configuration. *Please provide the required information necessary to answer your question.** You could always attempt to revert to the previous version to confirm if it's a 2004 issue.

Comment: [There are no known samba issues with 2004.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-2004).  So the error is caused by a configuration change caused by the feature update being installed.  This sort of configuration change is often seen, after a feature update is installed, when options that were enabled or disabled are set to whatever their default suggested value.

Answer (score 0):

Start button --->Run ---> regedit ---> enter
Then go to:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters

Open folder "Parameters" and there you'll find "AllowInsecureGuestAuth". Double click on "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" and change "Value Data" to 1 instead of 0. Clik OK and that should be all.

Comment: Didn't work. In Windows 10 version 1803, that key does not exist. Adding it and setting it to 1 also had no effect. Besides that, I'm not using insecure authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling SMB Direct (Settings -> Apps -> Apps & Features -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off).

Comment: Don't see "SMB Direct" in the list. I ended up buying a new computer and everything is working again.